# Controlling udp traffic with linux tc command

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, tc, dd-wrt

Setup: A client laptop (mac) connected to a Wi-Fi router wirelessly (atheros NIC with dd-wrt firmware). A server (linux) is directly connected to the router over ethernet interface. Now I am testing throughput with iperf3;

At server

```
iperf3 -s
```

At client

```
iperf3 -R -c 192.168.1.121 -t 60 -b 50M
```

That is, the client is downloading from server (-R option is used). This is TCP traffic (with reno congestion control). With this I get a continuous throughput of ~50 Mbps as expected. Congestion does exist at random time which makes the throughput drop at those moments. Which is fine. Now I am trying to control the traffic flow from Wi-Fi router to Client (i.e. Wi-Fi egress port). To do this, I am using tc utility of linux.

At Wi-Fi router:

```
tc qdisc add dev ath0 root tbf rate 5mbit burst 32kbit latency 400ms
```

As soon as it is executed, the throughput gets down to 5Mbps as expected.

Problem: If I do UDP instead of TCP:

```
iperf3 -R -c 192.168.1.121 -t 60 -b 50M -u
```

the `-u` option to generate UDP traffic, which also work fine. But when the same tc command is generate to control the traffic, the UDP throughput gets drop to 0 Mbps. It only gets back to 50Mbps, when the tc qdisc control is delted.

What might be the possible cause?