Is Linux tc tool only useful for tcp traffic?
Is the tc tool only useful for TPC traffic, or can it also be used to control other protocols like UDP traffic?

Essentially the same question, but longer, and without an answer at the moment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762050/controlling-udp-traffic-with-linux-tc-command

thanks for the info.

@waltinator if you can determine whether tc can control UDP by reading its man page, perhaps you can enlighten the rest of us. Please stop sending people to man pages unless you’ve checked yourself (recently) that they answer the question.

tc is used for 'shaping' a TCP connection. UDP doesnt have connections, each UDP packet is sent on its own, with no connection to be shaped.

@waltinator It's not. It's used for Traffic Control. The man page even mentions allowing to specify protocol, which makes no sense if it was made for TCP. The results of shaping UDP will of course differ wildly from shaping TCP, but tc can drop packets. It can even drop things not IP.

Thank you all, I will read manual carefully.
